# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute entrypoint stage 'client' due to errors, provided by 'modid'

Tags: java, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge, minecraft-fabric

I don't really know why I am getting this error. I have developed this mod, and this mod uses a MongoDB dependency. I have correctly listed the dependency in the build.gradle, but still, it is giving me this error. I tried running it through ./gradlew runClient, and it worked fine. However, when I tried to build it, it gave me this error when I tested it in Minecraft. I have tried different versions, but my problem is not solved. It gave me this error when I attempted to run it. I have tried reading the error, but I am not even able to find the error. Can anyone help me in finding the error and the solution to it?
**// Don't do that.

```
Time: 2024-01-21 18:23:35
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute entrypoint stage 'client' due to errors, provided by 'modid'!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.lambda$invoke0$0(EntrypointUtils.java:51)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.gatherExceptions(ExceptionUtil.java:33)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:49)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:35)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.Hooks.startClient(Hooks.java:53)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.<init>(class_310.java:458)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:211)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:468)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.util.DefaultLanguageAdapter.create(DefaultLanguageAdapter.java:50)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointStorage$NewEntry.getOrCreate(EntrypointStorage.java:117)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointContainerImpl.getEntrypoint(EntrypointContainerImpl.java:53)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:47)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:226)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:112)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 13 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.lambda$invoke0$0(EntrypointUtils.java:51)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.gatherExceptions(ExceptionUtil.java:33)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:49)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:35)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.Hooks.startClient(Hooks.java:53)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.<init>(class_310.java:458)

-- Initialization --
Details:
    Modules: 
        ADVAPI32.dll:Advanced Windows 32 Base API:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        COMCTL32.dll:User Experience Controls Library:6.10 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPT32.dll:Crypto API32:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTBASE.dll:Base cryptographic API DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTSP.dll:Cryptographic Service Provider API:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DBGHELP.DLL:Windows Image Helper:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DNSAPI.dll:DNS Client API DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        GDI32.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IMM32.DLL:Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IPHLPAPI.DLL:IP Helper API:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNEL32.DLL:Windows NT BASE API Client DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNELBASE.dll:Windows NT BASE API Client DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        MpOav.dll:IOfficeAntiVirus Module:4.18.23110.3 (9ebb3643d539a6fc4659898b1df3124d5da4c0a9):Microsoft Corporation
        NLAapi.dll:Network Location Awareness 2:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        NSI.dll:NSI User-mode interface DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        NTASN1.dll:Microsoft ASN.1 API:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Ole32.dll:Microsoft OLE for Windows:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        OleAut32.dll:OLEAUT32.DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        PSAPI.DLL:Process Status Helper:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Pdh.dll:Windows Performance Data Helper DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        RPCRT4.dll:Remote Procedure Call Runtime:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SHCORE.dll:SHCORE:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SHELL32.dll:Windows Shell Common Dll:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USER32.dll:Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USERENV.dll:Userenv:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        VCRUNTIME140.dll:MicrosoftпїЅ C Runtime Library:14.29.30139.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        VERSION.dll:Version Checking and File Installation Libraries:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINHTTP.dll:Windows HTTP Services:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINMM.dll:MCI API DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WS2_32.dll:Windows Socket 2.0 32-Bit DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WSOCK32.dll:Windows Socket 32-Bit DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Wldp.dll:Windows Lockdown Policy:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        amsi.dll:Anti-Malware Scan Interface:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        bcrypt.dll:Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        bcryptPrimitives.dll:Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        clbcatq.dll:COM+ Configuration Catalog:2001.12.10941.16384 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        combase.dll:Microsoft COM for Windows:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dbgcore.DLL:Windows Core Debugging Helpers:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc.DLL:DHCP Client Service:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc6.DLL:DHCPv6 Client:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        fwpuclnt.dll:FWP/IPsec User-Mode API:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        gdi32full.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.19041.3758 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        java.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        javaw.exe:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        jemalloc.dll
        jimage.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        jli.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        jna4060706775780150933.dll:JNA native library:6.1.4:Java(TM) Native Access (JNA)
        jsvml.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        jvm.dll:OpenJDK 64-Bit server VM:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        kernel.appcore.dll:AppModel API Host:10.0.19041.3758 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        lwjgl.dll
        management.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        management_ext.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        msvcp140.dll:MicrosoftпїЅ C Runtime Library:14.29.30139.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        msvcp_win.dll:MicrosoftпїЅ C Runtime Library:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        msvcrt.dll:Windows NT CRT DLL:7.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        mswsock.dll:Microsoft Windows Sockets 2.0 Service Provider:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        napinsp.dll:E-mail Naming Shim Provider:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        ncrypt.dll:Windows NCrypt Router:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        net.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        nio.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        ntdll.dll:NT Layer DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        perfos.dll:Windows System Performance Objects DLL:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pnrpnsp.dll:PNRP Name Space Provider:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        profapi.dll:User Profile Basic API:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rasadhlp.dll:Remote Access AutoDial Helper:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rsaenh.dll:Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        sechost.dll:Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        shlwapi.dll:Shell Light-weight Utility Library:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        sunmscapi.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        ucrtbase.dll:MicrosoftпїЅ C Runtime Library:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        vcruntime140_1.dll:MicrosoftпїЅ C Runtime Library:14.29.30139.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        verify.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
        win32u.dll:Win32u:10.0.19041.3930 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        windows.storage.dll:Microsoft WinRT Storage API:10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        winrnr.dll:LDAP RnR Provider DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        wshbth.dll:Windows Sockets Helper DLL:10.0.19041.3636 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        zip.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.3.0:Microsoft
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:211)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:468)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)

**
```